# Set multi colour treeviewitem header programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

I build a TreeView through code to match an xml document and I'm setting the header of each TreeViewItem through code to match the tag name and (if applicable) a significant attribute.

[image: https://image.prntscr.com/image/Ns6ilv7lRCa1LVHdP5OIwQ.png]

It looks a bit boring though so I would like to set the tag name to be one colour and the attribute value to be a different colour, but I can't figure out if that is even possible.

Can anyone enlighten me, is this possible and if so how would I go about it?

**EDIT**

Just to clarify what I'd like to do is:

[blue]name - [/blue][yellow]attribute[/yellow]

So the first asset, would have "Asset - " be blue, and "hands" be yellow.

**EDIT2**

By popular demand here is the code I'm using to create the TreeView :)

```
private TreeView CreateTree() {
    xmlDocument = XDocument.Load(FullPath, LoadOptions.SetLineInfo);
    xmlDocument.DescendantNodes().OfType < XComment > ().Remove();

    var tree = new TreeView {
        Name = "treeview_1",
        Background = (SolidColorBrush) new BrushConverter().ConvertFrom("#1e1e1e")
    };


    var firstNode = xmlDocument.Descendants().First();
    var treeItm = new TreeViewItem {
        Header = Utilities.GenerateName(firstNode),
        Tag = firstNode.AbsoluteXPath(),
        Foreground = Brushes.WhiteSmoke
    };

    treeItm.Selected += NodeSelected;
    tree.Items.Add(treeItm);
    AddNodes(xmlDocument.Descendants().First(), treeItm);
    return tree;
}

private void AddNodes(XElement lastNode, TreeViewItem lastTreeItm) {
    var xElements = lastNode.Descendants().ToList();
    if (xElements.Any()) {
        var treeItm = new TreeViewItem {
            Header = Utilities.GenerateName(xElements.First()),
            Tag = xElements.First().AbsoluteXPath(),
            Foreground = Brushes.WhiteSmoke
        };
        treeItm.Selected += NodeSelected;
        lastTreeItm.Items.Add(treeItm);
        AddNodes(xElements.First(), treeItm);
    }


    var sibl = (XElement) lastNode.NextNode;
    if (sibl != null) {
        var treeItm = new TreeViewItem {
            Header = Utilities.GenerateName(sibl),
            Tag = sibl.AbsoluteXPath(),
            Foreground = Brushes.WhiteSmoke
        };
        treeItm.Selected += NodeSelected;
        ((TreeViewItem) lastTreeItm.Parent).Items.Add(treeItm);
        AddNodes(sibl, treeItm);
    }
}
```

**EDIT3**

Here's the code for name generation, I forgot to add that in the latest edit.
I've removed most of the code from the switch case as it's just more of the same.

```
public class Utilities
{
    public static string GenerateName(XElement node)
    {
        switch (node.Name.LocalName)
        {
            case "Time":
                return "Time - " + GetAttr(node, "Id");
            default:
                if(node.Attribute("Id")?.Value != null)
                    return node.Name.LocalName + " - " + node.Attribute("Id")?.Value;
                return node.Name.LocalName;
        }   
    }

    private static string GetAttr(XElement node, string id)
    {
        return node.Attribute(id) != null ? node.Attribute(id)?.Value : "";
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted the code to your TreeView, but in essence, you only need to set the forground (color) property of each TreeViewItem.

Comment: I considered doing that but it's split into multiple functions that take care of the different aspects it seemed impractical, but foreground would only get me whole colour (right?)
What I want is to have like 
<blue>name:</blue><yellow>attribute</yellow>
I hope that makes it clearer? :)

Comment: you should post xaml code

Comment: First, are you modifying the TreeView properties in xaml or the code behind? From the original question it sounded like the C# code behind but from your edit it looks like you want to accomplish this in the xaml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
            <TreeViewItem>
                <TreeViewItem.Header>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="Asset - " Foreground="Blue"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="hands" Foreground="Yellow"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </TreeViewItem.Header>
            </TreeViewItem>
```

This should be what you are looking for. By using the StackPanel, you can set up two TextBlocks with different Forecolors.

**EDIT**

Since you are doing this in C#, you mainly just need to change the way that you are getting the Header property for each of your TreeViewItems.

It looks like you use `Utilities.GenerateName()` to get the Headers. Instead of doing this directly, you could bring the names in and add them to a string

(`String fullHeader = Utilities.GenerateName()`).

Then use some logic to determine how the string needs to be split. Assuming you had 2 values ( I.E. `String.Split()` returned an array of Strings with a size of 2),
you would then just make `TextBlocks` with the desired `Foreground` property and set the text properties to the new Strings.

I.e `TextBlock1.Text = YourStringArray[0]` and `TextBlock2.Text = YourStringArray[1]`.

The logic can be however you want to split the strings and based on how you are getting the names, you could even set up the logic in your `Utilities.GenerateName()` method.

The biggest part you will need to accomplish what you want is the `StackPanel`.

As an example, you could do something like this:

```
StackPanel myStackPanel = new StackPanel();
myStackPanel.Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal;
var treeItm = new TreeViewItem
{
    Header = myStackPanel,
    Tag = xElements.First().AbsoluteXPath(),
    Foreground = Brushes.WhiteSmoke
}
```

Comment: I am indeed doing it with C# code :) (you can see the code in the new edit)

Comment: I've added the GenerateName method too, it's pretty simple code really, I just forgot to add it in the last edit.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have the time to add much more but I'll update this later if you need additional assistance.

Comment: Not necessary this was perfect!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of assign TreeViewItem header directly to text,you can assign to a StackPanel with two TextBlocks inside

```
        StackPanel stackPanel = new StackPanel();
        stackPanel.Children.Add(new TextBlock { Text = Utilities.GenerateName(...), Foreground = Brushes.Red });
        stackPanel.Children.Add(new TextBlock { Text = Utilities.GetAttr(...), Foreground = Brushes.Yellow });
        stackPanel.Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal;

        var treeItm = new TreeViewItem {
        Header = stackPanel,
        Tag = firstNode.AbsoluteXPath(),
    };
```